# how can I update the state variable content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code as below:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Meeting from "./util/Meeting";
export default function TestMeeting(){
    const [peerList, setPeerList] = useState();
    const [meeting, setMeeting] = useState();
    let peerName;
    let sUsrAg = navigator.userAgent;
    if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Edg") > -1) {
        peerName = "Edge";
    } else {
        if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Chrome") > -1) {
            peerName = "Chrome";
        } else {
            if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Firefox") > -1) {
                peerName = "Firefox";
            } else {
                if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Safari") > -1) {
                    peerName = "Safari";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        let temp = new Meeting();
        temp.setDebug(true);
        temp.on("data", param => {
            console.log("Data Event Recevied:" + JSON.stringify(param));
        })
        temp.on("initialPeerList", (newPeerList) => {
            console.log("initialPeerList event recevied");
            console.log(newPeerList);
            setPeerList(newPeerList);
        });
        temp.on("newPeer", (newPeer) => {
            console.log("newPeer event recevied");
            console.log(peerList);
        });
        temp.on("removePeer", socketId => {
            console.log("removePeer event recevied");
            
        });
        temp.on("stream", param => {
            console.log("A stream event received:" + JSON.stringify(param));
            
        })
        temp.join(peerName);
        setMeeting(temp);
    }, [peerName]);   
    return (
        <>
        </>
    )
}
```

The "initialPeerList" event is received first and the `peerList` state variable should be updated.
After that, when the "newPeer"event is received, suppose the content of `peerList` state variable should not undefined, however, it does.

I have followed the page:
[useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

However, it does not solve the problem.

Why is this like that and how would I be able to fix it?

Comment: FYI, there's no reason to use `peerName` as a dependency for your `useEffect` hook since it never changes

Comment: The compiler told me to do so.

Comment: You mean the linter. I suppose it won't hurt but sometimes I find `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` a bit overzealous

Comment: I know in this cause, it doesn't matter; however, I just want to make the linter output clearer.